# How to let child view controller add UISearchBar to parent's UINavigationController?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

How to let child view controller modify navigation controller?

I am faced with this problem right now, and have not been able to find a solution that works, let alone one that works well.

Basically, right now I have a `UINavigationController` that contains a `UITableViewController` with a search bar in the navigation bar. So far so good - everything works well.

However, I would like to show some custom views between the navigation bar and the top of the table view at times. To do this, I figured it would be best to create another view controller (let's call it the `ContainerViewController`), which is presented by the navigation controller. This container view controller holds the table view controller as a child, and can insert any custom view it wishes to. The view controller hierarchy should look like this:

```
UINavigationController
    ContainerViewController
        UITableViewController (with UISearchDisplayController)
```

Now I am faced with a problem, since the search bar of the `UISearchDisplayController` should be displayed in the navigation bar (by calling `didSetupSearchDisplayController`), but I obviously want all logic pertaining to it kept in the `UITableViewController`. I need the container view controller to sort of act as a go-between here. I have tried to figure this out, but haven't managed a solution yet.

Here is how I instantiate the table view controller and add it as a child in the container view controller.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Load view controller from storyboard
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
    self.contentViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyListViewController"];
    self.contentViewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    // Add its view to the content view
    [self addChildViewController:self.contentViewController];
    [self.container addSubview:self.contentViewController.view];
    [self.contentViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    // Set up constraints
    [self.contentViewController.view autoPinEdgesToSuperviewEdgesWithInsets:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
}
```

In the child view controller, I have noticed that `self.navigationController` is nil in `viewDidLoad` but not in `didMoveToParentViewController`. So the following works:

```
- (void)didMoveToParentViewController:(UIViewController *)parent {
    // Hide separator below navigation bar
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.clipsToBounds = YES;
}
```

But I cannot set the search bar to display in the navigation bar, nor can I set the navigation bar title (with `self.title = ...`) from within the child view controller.

Would appreciate any help.

**EDIT:** Here is some code I use in the `UITableViewController` (the contained view) to create the search display controller:

```
UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] init];
self.mySearchDisplayController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:searchBar contentsController:self];

// Show search bar in navigation bar (instead of in its own bar underneath)
self.searchDisplayController.displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar = YES;

// Set self as delegate to search display controller and its table view
self.searchDisplayController.delegate = self;
self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsDelegate = self;
```

I have tried doing this both in `viewDidLoad`, where the `self.navigationController` is nil, and in `didMoveToParentViewController`, where the navigation controller exists, but it does not seem to matter. My guess is that the `displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar` magic happens *after the child view is  instantiated but before it is added as a child view* (and thus gets access to the navigation controller).

Comment: Hi erwald, I am facing the same situation as you. Were you able to find a solution?

Comment: @erwald did you find a way of making this work?

Answer (score 0):

can you use

```
self.parentViewController.navigationController
```

to get the reference to the navigation controller from within the container view?

Comment: Do you mean from within the contained view?

I don't actually need to reference it. I think it should all be done "automatically" when adding the search display controller, no? I shall edit my answer with some of the code I use there.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you find your answer. We use this to set the title of our navigation controller

```
self.navigationItem.title=@"Name of view goes here";
```

You should be able to use `self.navigationItem` to get a handle to the navigation bar.